# How would I sniff kline data packets

Tags: arduino

I have a board that is using kline to communicate and I have a tool that can read the software from that board. I want to see the communication that is happening between the two to see how the tool is able to read the firmware from that board.
I didn't find any tool or any information on how to sniff kline packets. Found only how to sniff CAN packets.

I it is possible to sniff data using arduino or raspberry or any other tool.

All I'm interested in is making a software that can read the firmware from that board.

Comment: what is "kline"? do you have any references?

Comment: Possibly http://www.crystorient.com/kline-software

Comment: K-line is serial data transfer single wire protocol i think it has multiple names (kwp2000, kw2000, j1962...).

Comment: Thanks ahmed but that is not what i want.i have an ECU that uses kwp2000 protocol and want to sniff the data that it sends in order to understand how a tool i have can dump the firmware from that ECU